# How to format string to money

Tags: c#

I have a string like `000000000100`, which I would like to convert to 1.00 and vice versa.

Leading zero will be remove, last two digit is the decimal.

I give more example :

```
000000001000 <=> 10.00
000000001005 <=> 10.05
000000331150 <=> 3311.50
```

Below is the code I am trying, it is giving me result without decimal :

```
amtf = string.Format("{0:0.00}", amt.TrimStart(new char[] {'0'}));
```

Comment: For the other way round multiply by 100 and use `PadLeft(12,'0')` of the string

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Convert the string to a decimal then divide it by 100 and apply the currency format string:

```
string.Format("{0:#.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(myMoneyString) / 100);
```

Edited to remove currency symbol as requested and convert to decimal instead.

Comment: and you get the currency symbol for free :) simpler to use `0:#.00`

Comment: @ThePower Thanks, but 'C' will convert to currency, which will return a $ sign.

Comment: You should never use `float` or `double` to represent currency.

Comment: Argh for me it keeps saying that it can't convert to a DateTime, also when I use {0:C}

Comment: Why not use double or float? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Shouldn't you use "F2" instead of "#.00"?

Answer (score 76):

you will need to convert it to decimal first, then format it in money format.

EX:

```
decimal decimalMoneyValue = 1921.39m;
string formattedMoneyValue = String.Format("{0:C}", decimalMoneyValue);
```

a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/soxxuW

Answer (score 60):

```
decimal value = 0.00M;
value = Convert.ToDecimal(12345.12345);
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C"));
//OutPut : $12345.12
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C1"));
//OutPut : $12345.1
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C2"));
//OutPut : $12345.12
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3"));
//OutPut : $12345.123
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C4"));
//OutPut : $12345.1234
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C5"));
//OutPut : $12345.12345
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C6"));
//OutPut : $12345.123450
```

Console output:
[image]

Comment: This one will properly respect culture variance. Cultural differences can not only change the symbol, but the digit separators as well (and theoretically the position of the currency symbol).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 23):

It works!

```
decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39m; 
string html = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", moneyvalue); 
Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Output

```
Order Total: $1,921.39
```

Comment: What if I have to remove the dollar sign?

Comment: @ParisQianSen use N instead of C

Answer (score 18):

Once you have your string in a double/decimal to get it into the correct formatting for a specific locale use

```
double amount = 1234.95;

amount.ToString("C") // whatever the executing computer thinks is the right fomat

amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-ie"))    //  €1,234.95
amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-es"))    //  1.234,95 € 
amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))    //  £1,234.95 

amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-au"))    //  $1,234.95
amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"))    //  $1,234.95
amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-ca"))    //  $1,234.95
```

Comment: `GetCultureInfo` doesn't appear to exist in UWP.

Answer (score 5):

Try simple like this

```
 var amtf = $"{Convert.ToDecimal(amt):#0.00}";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//Extra currency symbol and currency formatting: "€3,311.50":
String result = (Decimal.Parse("000000331150") / 100).ToString("C");

//No currency symbol and no currency formatting: "3311.50"
String result = (Decimal.Parse("000000331150") / 100).ToString("f2");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    string s ="000000000100";
    decimal iv = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(s, out iv);
    Console.WriteLine((iv / 100).ToString("0.00"));
```

Comment: You should never use `float` or `double` to represent currency.

Answer (score 2):

you can also do :

```
string.Format("{0:C}", amt)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used this string format to display currency from decimal values without the symbol.

**String format:**

```
string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", decimalValue)
```

**Example:**

```
var decimalNumbers = new decimal[] { 1M, 10M, 100M, 1000M,10000M,100000M,1000000M,1000000000M };          

foreach (var decimalNumber in decimalNumbers)
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", decimalNumber));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39m;
string html = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", moneyvalue);
Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse to your string to a decimal first.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tests = new[] {"000000001000", "000000001005", "000000331150"};
foreach (var test in tests)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} <=> {1:f2}", test, Convert.ToDecimal(test) / 100);
}
```

Since you didn't ask for the currency symbol, I've used "f2" instead of "C"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
amtf =  amtf.Insert(amtf.Length - 2, ".");
```

Comment: that doesn't remove the leading zeros. If you're going down the simple string manipulation route you would need to add .Trim("0".ToCharArray()) to the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

```
 private string cxp(string txt) {
        try
        {

            decimal n;
            n = Math.Round( Convert.ToDecimal( txt),2);

            string newTxt;
            newTxt = Convert.ToString(n);
            //txt = txt.Replace(",", ".");
            //string newtxt = string.Format("{0:#.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(txt) );

            return newTxt.Replace(",", ".");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message ,"Error al parsear número");
            //throw;
            return txt;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string price = "100";
decimal priceDecimal;

if (Decimal.TryParse(price, out priceDecimal))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:C2}", priceDecimal));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid price value");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?