# Money format using float in c#

Tags: c#, realm

So I'm going to be creating an app using realmdb - realm does not support decimal data types as of yet so I have been looking for an equivalent. If you could imagine object 1 returns 50, object 2 returns 50 & object 3 returns 12 = 112 but after 30% it should return £78.40 - Right now its returning £78.4

Below is my current code.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Object Costs");
        float ObjectOne = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Object 2 Costs");
        float ObjectTwo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Object 3 Costs");
        float ObjectThree = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        float Total = ObjectOne + ObjectTwo + ObjectThree;


        Console.WriteLine("Total: " + NewLine + "£" + Total);

        Console.WriteLine("DISCOUNTED - 30% OFF!!!");



        Console.WriteLine(NewLine + "Final Total: " + "£" + (Total - Math.Round((Total / 100 * 30), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format string to money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615405/how-to-format-string-to-money)

Comment: You should look into string formatting in C#, for example: `yourfloat.ToString("0.00")`

Comment: if realmdb does not have decimal then I think it could be better to save as integers reprecenting cent or something but keep code as decimal. Using float for currencies gives a lot of problems.

Comment: @Innat3 Silly question - how could I do calculations with that number at a later point though if Its a string object or would I just need to state Im converting it back before doing the sum?

Comment: @BlairGibson you just use `.ToString()` to display the number as a string in the desired format. You can just keep making operations with the original float, and use `.ToString()` whenever you need to display it again

Comment: @BlairGibson, whenever you want to display number in particular format use `.ToString()`. This will format your number and will keep number it's original type. I would also request you to use decimal datatype when you are working with money. I added reason and documentation for it in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format your float value using `ToString("0.00")`;

```
var discountedRate = (Total - Math.Round((Total / 100 * 30), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)).ToString("0.00");

Console.WriteLine($"Final Total:£ {discountedRate}");
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Qd5If)

---

**Just a note:** If you are dealing with money then use [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) instead of float

From MSDN:

> The decimal type has more precision and a smaller range than both
>   float and double, it's appropriate for financial and monetary
>   calculations.